# Python - Printing user input on screen

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is a basic simple Python question.. I want to take the name as an input from user and print it on screen. I am using PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2.3 IDE. My code is as follows:

```
name=input("Enter your name ")
print(name)
```

I am getting the below error. Should be a very simple fix.. but not getting it... Any suggestions.... I am new to Python.....

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/sourav/PycharmProjects/python_project/dummy1.py
Enter your name Sourav
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sourav/PycharmProjects/python_project/dummy1.py", line 1, in <module>
    name=input("Enter your name ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Sourav' is not defined
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: use `raw_input()` or convert your input to string and display.

Comment: Thanks Bhansa and UrbanConor... It is actually an issue with the version.... In Python Version 2, raw_input() is considered as a string while input() runs the input as an expression. I wouldn't have faced the issue in version 3. I was using version 2.

Answer (score 1):

Either use `raw_input()` here.

```
name = raw_input("Enter your name ")
print(name)
```

Or give input as "Sourav" with the quotes using [`input`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x)